# error while running gulp serve when changes are made in .js files

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, bower

i am changing few UI files on the fly, but most of the time my gulp serve crashes with below error.

after undoing those changes also but it stills fails .

as a work around i need to delete the bower componets and re-install the UI components (npm install, bower install , gulp serve)
Error:

```
events.js:141
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

TypeError: must start with number, buffer, array or string
at fromObject (buffer.js:167:9)
at new Buffer (buffer.js:58:10)
at DestroyableTransform._transform (D:\Hygieia\UI\node
_modules\wiredep\wiredep.js:135:23)
at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (D:\Hygieia\UI
\node_modules\wiredep\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_st
ream_transform.js:184:10)
at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (D:\Hygieia\U
I\node_modules\wiredep\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_s
tream_transform.js:172:12)
at doWrite (D:\Hygieia\UI\node_modules\wiredep\node_mo
dules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:237:10)
at writeOrBuffer (D:\Hygieia\UI\node_modules\wiredep\n
ode_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_writable.js:227:5)

at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (D:\Hygieia\UI\
node_modules\wiredep\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_str
eam_writable.js:194:11)
at write (D:\Hygieia\UI\node_modules\gulp\node_modules
\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readabl
e.js:623:24)
at flow (D:\Hygieia\UI\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\
vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable
.js:632:7)

D:\Hygieia\UI>
```

any comments please on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you please post, what changes you are doing after that it starts failing. as per your error log, issue related to you are trying to access some resource, an in that it does not find event,